# a table is not being created

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a table but unfortunately, It's not being created
I guess my query has a problem I'm using this it was creating until I add many columns
Any help guys <3 sorry if it looks not clear but I tried so hard to know what's wrong now its been 2 hours trying

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = 
                "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+
                " ("+request_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " + ","+is_completed+" INT(10) " + ","+status+" INT(10) " +
                ","+is_paid+" INT(10) " + ","+is_cancelled+" INT(10) " + ","+is_client_rated+" INT(10) " +
                ","+is_walker_rated+" INT(10) " + ","+payment_mode+" INT(10) " +
                ","+distance+" FLOAT(8,2) " + ","+waiting_time+" FLOAT(8,2) " + ","+refund+" FLOAT(8,2) " +
                ","+pay_time+" FLOAT(8,2) " + ","+device_distance+" FLOAT(8,2) " + ","+time+" FLOAT(8,2) " + ","+total+" FLOAT(8,2) " +
                ","+promo_payment+" FLOAT(8,2) " + ","+D_latitude+" DOUBLE(89,2) " + ","+D_longitude+" DOUBLE(89,2) " +
                ","+latitude+" DOUBLE(89,2) " + ","+longitude+" DOUBLE(89,2) " + ","+date+" VARCHAR(255) " +
                ","+name+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+request_start_time+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+start_count_time+" VARCHAR(255) " +
                ","+end_trip_time+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+start_late_time+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+end_late_time+" VARCHAR(255) " +
                ","+late_client_min+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+created_at+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+security_key+" VARCHAR(255) " +
                ","+dest_address+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+req_create_user_time+" VARCHAR(255) " + ","+src_address+" VARCHAR(255)) " + ";";
```

Comment: First uninstall the app from the device and then rerun. If your app crashes post here the error log.

Comment: Oh of course just a sec

Comment: Bro, I'm so so sorry it worked tho I deleted the app twice but now it's working lol sorry really, The query is working

Comment: Can you please add your answer so I can mark as right

Comment: Fine, there is no need to add an answer. This is a very common problem answered many times. Just remember to do this every time that you make changes to a table's design by adding or renaming columns.

Comment: Of course, thank you, bro!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)